# xpath to xsd definition

Tags: xpath, schema

I am looking for a way to take a xpath for an instance xml file and use it to find the xsd element.  If possible are there any xsl or .net examples?

Comment: It is not entirely clear from the question - would loading the XML file, validating it against the schema, selecting the node according to XPath, and retrieving the type annotation of the node, be an acceptable answer? Or are you trying to do this without loading XML - by "applying" XPath directly to XSD?

Comment: In an ideal world I would go from xpath to xsd.  But I have no problem with using a sample xml document.